# What is the advantage of using Fractal over toArray() in PHP

Tags: php, api, oop

I have stumbled upon PHP League [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/simple-example/) which shows that the purpose is to ensure output format between storage and output (client).

I've been working with APIs for over a year, and I have constructed toArray() functions for most of my entities that I wish to return. With the aid of Eloquent, you can overload the toArray() function and decorate from there also if you have attached your entity model with Eloquent model.

Example:

```
public function toArray()
{
    $array = parent::toArray();
    $array['extra'] = true;
    ...
    return $array;
}
```

If Apis should be fast and lightweight, what advantages does PHP League's Fractal have over implementing a toArray() or have a format($data) function from a repository/manager? Is it due to OOP? if so can someone show an example?

Answer (score 0):

For me the advantages are:

- consistent response format enforced by passing models through Fractal's resource objects
- ability to rather easily change the response format throughout the application with a simple switch of a serialiser (e.g., from json-api to hal and possibly more). For json-api it does the boring stuff like splitting actual response data and root metadata. Also you can easily change response depending of `Accept` header, which might be harder with array (you'd need to restructure it and certainly you don't want that clutter in your controller).
- automation of links generation e.g., for pagination

I think first two are not exclusive to Fractal, but would be a purpose of having any abstraction for response formatting.

What is unclear for me, is where does something like Fractal belong? I'm a big fan of the view that the model should be able to represent itself, like it does with `__toString`. But then again one might argue that it's more a concern of the presentation than the model. With using fractal's pagination, embedding support it get even less clear, because that (for me) strays a bit beyond the presentation itself.

Speed concern is of course valid, but you can optimise elsewhere, e.g. by caching whole response content on something like varnish or some laravel package that performs the similar role if you don't have the infrastructure (caveat being that it's not applicable to every use case, authorised or varied user-specific responses being case in point).

As for examples I can recommend two, beside the package docs:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/fractal-practical-walkthrough/
- http://laravelista.com/laravel-fractal/

Would love to see some writeup of how something like Fractal can fit into a bigger, structured project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will be looking into the two recommended links because I couldnt find anything significant that can show me an advantage over toArray(). If I can wrap my head around this - Ill try to write a small follow up to see if it can be used in a bigger picture.

Comment: Looking forward to it. I've posted [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34275821/1105871), since can't decide how to go about abstracting response formatting in a Laravel-based API.