# where does a library like Fractal belong?

Tags: api, architecture, laravel-5.1

I was looking into [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com) (tldr : data object/collection to json formatting library) today and saw some benefits to using it. However it's functionality seems to span across multiple layers of the app I'm working on. Hence a question appeared -- where does a code utilising Fractal belong to? Model, service, controller, some other place? The examples given in the documentation at the project docs seem to favour putting it in the controller or right in a route callback (more complex examples seem to be coming from Laravel app and the author mentioned it in his book on API).

My concern is coupling -- if I put it in the controller, as most of the usage examples show, then I'm pretty much bound to it in the future. My first instinct is to abstract it a little, make that abstraction bound to a contract and then put it to use. Might sound over engineered, but the API I'm working on "is aspiring" to be [JSON-API](http://jsonapi.org) compliant, so exchanging such a "json formatter" for something else sounds less crazy. Besides I still need to format error messages and Fractal seems no to touch that at all.

I'd like to take advantage of support for Eloquent's paginator and embedded resources, because that's always a pain. Only doing that makes it awkward (to say the least) at presentation/control layer. Even in the Fractal docs they resort to adding some extra methods to the controller class to prep Fractal objects. It seems a bit weird to me, but maybe it's just me. That's why take it here.

I'm aware that it might be a matter of preference, but I'm counting on somebody to have a reasonably sounding one :). Or perhaps a better solution altogether, keeping in mind that automation and `json-api` compliance are key reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this once with an API class for a proprietary system with which my application needed to interface. The API returned objects that looked a lot like models, so I implemented a number of classes for the objects I needed and implemented a library to make the API calls and return the objects. Luckily, I only needed read access to the API, so my library implements only a small subset of the actions available.

Maybe you could abstract all the functionality you need (both Fractal and any Eloquent features) into a library class for which you have defined an interface. That way all the Fractal code is in one place and if you ever need to replace it, you just rewrite your custom library class (which might be a lot of work, but probably better than hunting down references to Fractal sprinkled throughout your code).

Comment: I think I came across a similar idea on : https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/3l66kn/looking_for_advice_on_how_to_implement_the/ . It does sound reasonable.